# Why does the number of rows increase in a SELECT statement with INNER JOIN when a second column is selected?

Tags: sql, select, self-join

I am writing some queries with self-joins in SQL Server. When I have only one column in the SELECT clause, the query returns a certain number of rows. When I add another column, from the second instance of the table, to the SELECT clause, the results increase by 1000 rows!

How is this possible?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I have a subquery in the FROM clause, which is also a self-join on the same table.

Comment: Can you include the SQL statement, or at least a sample?

Comment: Agreed: Impossible to answer without example code.

Comment: Without seeing the query it's a bit hard to tell, but based on your symptoms it sounds like you've a `group by` clause in there, and are not making perfect sense of how the latter works.

Comment: Thanks guys. I cannot paste the actual query due to confidentiality. I will have to make an analogous example.

Comment: Ok, I await in anticipation.  Meanwhile, don't worry, SQL is not broken :)

Answer (score 1):

> How is this possible?

the only thing I can think of is that you have `SELECT DISTINCT` and the additional column makes some results distinct that weren't before the additional column.

For example I would expect the second result to have many more rows

```
SELECT DISTINCT First_name From Table
```

vs

```
SELECT DISTINCT First_name, Last_name From Table
```

But if we had the actual SQL then something else might come to mind